# Connected RF Trace to Multiple Pads

Tags: rf, transmission-line

I'm trying to improve my RF routing skills. I want to connect a 450 MHz trace (21mil width) to a [RF6886TR13 power amplifier](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/412/f6886_data_sheet-1093420.pdf) that has 6 RF_OUT pins. What is the best way to make this connection? I've added a screenshot showing what I mean.

[image]

Comment: can you name the amplifier IC?

Comment: Amplifier part number: RF6886TR13

Comment: Added the link to the datasheet to your question. However, you're using a footprint that is pretty much completely unsuitable for the QFN package of the IC. The IC's datasheet specifies the recommended pad pattern, and you're diverting significantly from it. So, start by overhauling your footprint. That alone will solve a whole range of your problems.

Comment: The datasheet mentions a "Standard Evaluation Board" in many, many places. So, get the datasheet, schematics and other documents for that, and simply do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice @Marcus Müller. I didn't find the layout of the evaluation board but I found a top down photo that shows how those pins are connected

[image]